# Is there DMV for seeing view access count?

Tags: sql-server, view, dmv

I saw it once during a presentation when someone showed a query to get a count of how many times views have queried in a SQL server. I don't remember if it was from DMV or a combination of some other statistics, but I clearly remember when they ran a query that selects from a view and after it would show that count going up by one. Another interesting fact that I recall about the presentation was selecting from a CTE increased the count by two because SQL Server has to create a "temporary view" and later select from it.

Does anyone know how this can be demonstrated?

Answer (score 6):

No, but what the presenter was probably doing was using [Grant Fritchey's technique to search the plan cache for a string](http://www.scarydba.com/2012/07/02/querying-data-from-the-plan-cache/). You can search the plan cache for your view name.

That technique has a few drawbacks. It's very slow on a busy/large production server - it doesn't hold folks back by blocking, but it can just take a really long time to search, say, 10-100GB of query plans looking for a string. Also, it only searches the literal plan - if you have a view calling another view, the nested view's name may not show up in the query or the plan.

Comment: Wow, have you seen a server with 100GB of query plans? Were they genuine or unparameterized duplication?

Comment: Yeah, 1+TB RAM boxes with high uptime and diverse workloads.